# What is this plant growing behind daylilies?

Tags: bulbs

[image]

Can anyone identify this bulb plant?  Upstate NY

Comment: Maybe an Allium. If you rub a leaf, do your fingers come away smelling like onions or garlic? If it is an Allium, the flower bud will open into a spherical cluster of small flowers, probably purple, or maybe white.